# How to use Flutter FutureBuilder to load 4 or 5 heavy json data?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, splash-screen, progress-indicator

In my demo app, when starting I need to show full-page gif animation and same time in the background do heavy JSON data load. Once I get all the JSON data then create (a landing widget) page for the user.

Step:

- **main.dart**

  - loads the gift animation & gets the JSON data
  - once they get JSON stops the gif animation and re-directs to
    landing.dart page
- **landing.dart**

  - shows some JSON data link
  - when a user tries to see the details it asks the user to log in.
  - if the user wants to see the details tabs the login button
- **login.dart**

  - allow the user to log in if successful and redirects to home.dart page
- **home.dart**

I read a lot about how to get JSON. And how to use the CircularProgressIndicator. My problem is that I need to load 4 or 5 heavy JSON data and like to use my own animated gif instead of CircularProgressIndicator.

Most of the examples out there is dealing with only one JSON API. And most of the documentation that I read talks about FutureBuilder.

Is it possible that someone can help me to overcome these issues? All I need is someone to show me how to load 2 JSON API data in the background and show CircularProgressIndicator. And how to jump from CircularProgressIndicator to the landing page (scaffold widget).

Thanks

Comment: This Project is Loading data form multiple URL.
Github Code: https://github.com/nitishk72/Flutter-Github-API

Project Demo : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hD_HmpDyCqc

Comment: I can help you with this code only.

Comment: @nitishk72 thank you very much. I will check it.